# Solr query not working for field type "text"

Tags: python-2.7, solr

I am using solr data base for storing some tags information. To store the data I am using solr "text" field with below definition:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Below is the stored data:

```
  {
    "id": 568658sheib,
    "created_at":"2019-02-21T12:45:49Z",
    "tags":"tagone_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagtwo_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagthree_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagfour_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagfive_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagsix_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagsseven_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagseight_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagsnine_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagsten_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagsleven_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagstwelve_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagsthirteen_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo,tagsfourteen_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo"
   }
```

I am getting the result when I query like below:

```
id:568658sheib AND tags:tagone_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo
id:568658sheib AND tags:tagsfourteen_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo
```

But randomly if I pickup 2 tags like below result is not coming.

```
tags:tagseight_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo AND tags:tagsfourteen_tagsuserinfo_tagsnameuserinfo
```

Its very confusing. I have tried all kind of queries but no help. Kindly help with this.

Comment: In the working query you are using "q:xxxx" but in the failing query you show "tags:yyyyy". How are the fields "q" and "tags" defined in your schema?

Comment: @kellyfj sorry it was a typing mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: Use the "Analysis" page under Solr's admin interface to see exactly how your indexed content and your query string is being processed. The query tokens should be present on the indexing side to generate a hit.